# How make this slider with mouse over action?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created this slider and I want to mouse over action on numbers jquery but I can't seem to get it to work, Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Every time I tried something it seemed to break the slider.

thanks

**jsfiddle version**: http://jsfiddle.net/BijanZand/cmqkc59b/

Here is the current code:

```
function tabsrotate() {
    $("#slider_a, #slider_b").tabs({
        show: function (event, ui) {
            var lastOpenedPanel = $(this).data("lastOpenedPanel");
            if (!$(this).data("topPositionTab")) {
                $(this).data("topPositionTab", $(ui.panel).position().top);
            }
            $(ui.panel).hide().fadeIn(1500);
            if (lastOpenedPanel) {
                lastOpenedPanel.toggleClass("ui-tabs-hide").css("position", "absolute").css("top", "0").fadeOut(1500, function () {
                    $(this).css("position", "");
                });
            }
            $(this).data("lastOpenedPanel", $(ui.panel));
        }
    }).tabs('rotate', 7777, true);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    tabsrotate();

    $('.tabnavigation').css("display", "inline");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a `mouseover` event to your anchor using **jQuery** and inside this event **trigger the anchor** `click`:

Your `$(document).ready` will look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    tabsrotate();

    $('.tabnavigation').css("display", "inline");

    $('.tabnavigation li a').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).click();
    });

});
```